# How could I close all opened activities other than MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio

When my activity stack is like,

`MainActivtiy` -> `Activity1` -> `Activity2` -> `Activity3`

I need to go 3 back states to reach `MainActivtiy` from `Activity3`

I could be able to close opened activities from `Activity3` like,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

But, above code segment closes all activities including `MainActivtiy` and starts new `MainActivtiy`. I want to know are there any other options to do the task that I need. I dont want to create new Intent because it drops the data of static methods that I have created in my `MainActivtiy`.

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) which will bring the running activity on top and remove all other activities above it

Note : it will trigger the `onNewIntent` of already running activity otherwise mention `launchMode = "singleTask"` in activity tag, inside manifest

Comment: @ChyperX i am glad that i could help,happy coding